# NSPrintPanel and duplex setting issues

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing

I appear to have issues with duplex, two sided settings and core printing.

In 10.13 the duplex value is set before the panel is opened but not being reflected in the dialog UI. We are specifically setting two page mode but when the NSPrintPanel is shown in a modal state the two page checkbox is not set. If clicked and set or unset it seems to return the correct value in the printSettings on return, just not set the UI from the initial value in printSettings on opening. Duplex mode is the only setting we are have issues with : In principal we are doing :

```
NSPrintInfo* shared_info = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
PMPrintSettings shared_settings = (PMPrintSettings)shared_info.PMPrintSettings;
if (PMSetDuplex(shared_settings, kPMDuplexNoTumble) == noErr)
[shared_info updateFromPMPrintSettings];

NSPrintPanel* panel = [NSPrintPanel printPanel];
[panel runModalWithPrintInfo:shared_info];
```

Have I missed something ? Its as though the printPanel is using most settings from the given NSPrintInfo, but not the duplex value.

Thanks in advance.

**As an update :** The printer I'm using with support for two-sided is the HP Envy 5640 series. How ever the problem was reported on another printer so I don't think this is specific to this driver.

**Final Update** After not getting anywhere with this I opened a support case with Apple, only to be told

> The print dialog enforces its own duplex setting based on the printer capabilities and past usage. A developer cannot override that behaviour when showing the print dialog

I personally think this is a bug, but was told to open a 'feature request'. I'm updating this in case any other developer runs into a similar situation.

Comment: Is the two page checkbox added by the printer driver? Or do you mean the Two-Sided popup button?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure. I know this is not an option all printers support, but I'm not sure if this is specifically added by the driver. My gut feeling given this has a dedicated PMSetDuplex API, is this is an option drivers can choose to display, but maintained by macOS.

The option is the check-box, called "Two-Sided" that appears next to the Black and White option near copies. I believe this is linked to the two sided popup in the 'layout' panel, as setting the two sided checkbox alters the popup.